# How can I transfer photos from iPhone to Samsung Galaxy phone with location information?

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos, android

I'm trying to transfer photos from iphone to my new samsung galaxy note 20, but the smart switch does not work for me somehow (It asks me to retry after I input my iCloud password, but my friend's iphone works on the same cable). I wonder if there's any other way that I could use to transfer photos, if the location and time information could be kept with photos, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: The location metadata is stored (usually) *inside* the actual picture. Have you tried a free tier of a cloud storage service like Google Drive or Dropbox?

Comment: hi Steve Chambers, I have tried yet, are you saying that if i use Google Drive to transfer those location will come with pictures? Thanks

Comment: I *believe* so. But as I have not tried it myself it is a comment rather than an answer. EG it **should** work, and the cost of doing so is only a little time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I found I could transfer all my data by iCloud. By default, it shows transfer data of "last 30 days" only, but there's a small gray arrow at right, by clicking this you could choose "all data", and which works perfectly.